# Internal and external module, shared between projects

Tags: typescript

Me and a friend are currently working on a project where we have a client(html5, run in browsers) and a server (node/io.js). The client is merged into a single file and the server is module based, requiring files as they are needed.

Now to the issue, we have a Constants file with enums being shared between the two projects, though, i cannot figure out how to write it to make it work properly, Since the client has internal modules and server has external.
It looks sortof like

```
module Constants {
    export enum Direction {
        Left, Up, Right, Down
    };
};
```

Putting export = Constants at the end makes things get wierd, Then the client does not know what the Constants object is. Not putting it won't make the server find it... So... what should be my approach here?

Answer (score 0):

> Not putting it won't make the server find it... So... what should be my approach here?

## FIX

Use external modules everywhere. Trust me you will thank me later (https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md)

## Workaround

you can put it on `globals` in node ... which is similar to `window` in the browser where *internal modules* actually end up.

But you will now need to make an untype checked `require` call to the .js file to get it to execute in the node runtime (effectively a `script` tag).

Comment: I think i've stumbled upon that link before. though i don't agree on all points (runtime errors have never been a problem for me since /// reference will make sure the files are being built into the file in the correct order). And if i'm using external modules, then i need require? or something else. Cause i'd like to have a single file in the end since i'm going to use it for mobile purposes, extra http request will be bad. 

Then i get the issue with letting an external program build it(like closure compiler), wouldn't that justg give unnecesary code? Correct me if i'm wrong :)

Comment: `And if i'm using external modules, then i need require` yes require along with a runtime support. Runtime is built into node (commonjs), and can be used in the browser (e.g. using webpack)

Comment: `Then i get the issue with letting an external program build it(like closure compiler), wouldn't that justg give unnecesary code` webpack will generate a single file for your frontend for you

Comment: I've been playing around with this idea now for a while, but with using browserify instead of webpack, i might try the latter though, as i ran into some problems. 

It seems like PIXI, one lib i'm using is build with browserify so it has some internal "require" calls, which makes browserify go nuts. It tries to require files that are not there. Search/Replace in the pixi.js bin seems to fix this issue.